# Android Application crashed on android 10

Tags: android

My Android App is crashed on android 10 Q mobile but I am unable to reproduce this crash and resolve it.

This is the error message:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.clearcut.service.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
       at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1741)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1651)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:705)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.zza(:22)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf.zze(:30)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.zza(:15)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient.zza(:103)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient.connect(:142)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.connect(:224)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.zab(:47)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.handleMessage(:173)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.base.zap.dispatchMessage(:8)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Here are the firebase crash pics:

[image: crashed screenshots from firebase]

Comment: My guess would be there's something wrong with those devices (they're all from one OEM) and there's nothing wrong with your app's code.  If anything, try updating your Google Play Services library versions.

Answer (score 0):

please register your service in manifest if not ex: `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />`

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />These permissions are added kindly can you tell me which service i add in manifest file thanks

Comment: com.google.android.gms this service register  in manifest file  ?

Comment: have you registered your service class in the manifest?

Comment: android:name=".service.BackgroundService"
android:name="com.clevertap.android.sdk.pushnotification.CTNotificationIntentService"
  <service android:name="com.clevertap.android.sdk.pushnotification.fcm.FcmMessageListenerService">
 android:name=".service.FirebaseNotificationService"
 <service android:name=".service.FCMTokenService">
 android:name=".service.UpdateOneSignalService"
These are registered in Menifiest

Comment: try adding following intent filter to your service  <service
            android:name="your service name"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.clearcut.service.START"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

Comment: You do know that `com.google.android.gms` isn't the asker's app, right?  That's Google Play Services.

Comment: its give error on adding com.google.android.gms this service in menifist.